# InvalidCastException: Azure Durable Functions Error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, azure-durable-functions

Locally testing Azure Durable Functions with VSCode + JavaScript. Able to successfully trigger the HTTP triggered Orchestration Client and can even see the request headers + body no problem. However, I receive the following error when attempting to trigger the Orchestrator:

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationContext' to type 'System.String'

I don't understand why DurableOrchestrationContext is trying to be turned into a string. 
Code calling the Orchestrator:

```
context.bindings.patient = [{
    FunctionName: "OrchestratorJS",
    Input: req,
    InstanceId: id
}];
```

Notes:
- I tried sending just a string as the Input, but to no effect. 
- I have successfully created Durable Functions for a different project which makes this even more frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The Functions runtime is trying to cast DurableOrchestrationContext to a string because of [how languages are handled in Functions v2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Language-Extensibility). Unlike v1, v2 runs JavaScript functions through a Node language worker hosted in a different process from the runtime host. The language worker and the host communicate via gRPC protocol. When a function is called, the runtime host must pass bound parameter information to the function over gRPC. Parameters bound to complex objects, like DurableOrchestrationContext, must be serialized to JSON strings, passed via gRPC, and finally rehydrated for a function to consume them.

We introduced DurableOrchestrationContext to string conversion in the 1.4.0 release. Could you try updating to the latest version of the extension (1.5.0) and trying your function again?

Comment: As it turns out **one** of my fields (out of 226) was an empty "" string, so JSON serialization didn't know what to do with it. Apparently PowerShell (using as client) doesn't care but JSON.parse certainly does. Thank you for the information. Expected the function to send the JSON as an object or string rather than try to serialize the JSON (Previous experience was with Binary files so didn't have this issue before).